# RC6 Implementation giving undesired results

Tags: c++, cryptography

I am trying to get an RC6 implementation from the [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1ab5/586cc5d356330aef8a868aaa6c9bee493796.pdf) working. I have double checked against the algorithm in the paper and am not sure where I went wrong although my suspicion is key scheduling.

My current output is this:

> PLAIN   : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

> KEY     : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

> ENCRYPT : 30 48 87 4e 00 69 ff 12 da 49 ad 9c 50 8a 0c 96

> DECRYPT : 80 53 4a d9 78 b9 37 54 64 8f d4 1d e0 10 56 5d

Trying to achieve the first test vector from the paper:

> plaintext 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

> user key 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

> ciphertext 8f c3 a5 36 56 b1 f7 78 c1 29 df 4e 98 48 a4 1e

```
#pragma once

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

#include "types.h"

using std::max;
using std::ceil;
using std::pow;
using std::vector;
using std::numeric_limits;

// Binary expansion of e - 2
template<class T> static const T P = 
    T(ceil((M_E - 2) * pow(2, numeric_limits<T>::digits)));
// Binary expansion of ϕ - 1 where ϕ is the golden ratio
template<class T> static const T Q = 
    T(((1.618033988749895 - 1) * pow(2, numeric_limits<T>::digits)));

class rc6 {
private:
    
    // Used for indices on blocks to match paper
    enum {
        A = 0, 
        B = 1, 
        C = 2, 
        D = 3
    };

    static const unsigned MAX_KEY_LEN = 2040;
        
    /**
    * Rotate a N-bit value left
    * @param word: value to rotate
    * @param shift: bits to roll
    */
    template<class T> static inline T rol(T word, unsigned shift)
    {
        return (word << shift) | (word >> (numeric_limits<T>::digits - shift));
    }

    /**
    * Rotate a N-bit value right
    * @param word: value to rotate
    * @param shift: bits to roll
    */
    template<class T> static inline T ror(T word, unsigned shift)
    {
        return (word >> shift) | (word << (numeric_limits<T>::digits - shift));
    }
    
    /**
    * Create key schedule @S from input @key
    * @param key: key bytes
    * @param S: destination for key schedule
    * @param r: number of rounds
    */
    template<class T> static void key_schedule(vector<u8>& key, vector<T>& S, unsigned r = 20) {
        // The user supplies a key of b bytes
        unsigned b = key.size() * sizeof(T);
        unsigned b_bits = b * 8;
        
        if (b > MAX_KEY_LEN)
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Key can't be greater than 2040 bits, got %u.\n", b_bits);
        
        // Sufficient zero bytes are appended to give a key length equal to a non-zero 
        // integral number of words
        for ( ; key.size() % sizeof(T) != 0; b++)
            key.push_back(0x00);
        
        // key bytes are then loaded in little-endian fashion into an array of c w-bit 
        // words L[0], ..., L[c - 1]
        const unsigned c = key.size();
        vector<T> L(key.data(), static_cast<u8*>(key.data()) + b);
        
        const unsigned v = 3 * max(c, 2 * r + 4);
        unsigned i = 0, j = 0;

        S[0] = P<T>;
        for (i = 1; i < 2 * r + 3; i++)
            S[i] = S[i - 1] + Q<T>;
        
        i = 0;
        unsigned A = 0, B = 0;
        for (unsigned s = 1; s <= v; s++) {
            A = S[i] = rol(S[i] + A + B, 3);
            B = L[j] = rol(L[j] + A + B, A + B);
            i = (i + 1) % (2 * r + 4);
            j = (j + 1) % c;
        }
    }
    
public:
    /**
    * Encrypt @plaintext using @key for @r rounds
    * @param plaintext: plain text to encrypt
    * @param key: key bytes
    * @param r: number of rounds
    */
    template<class T> static void encrypt(vector<T>& plaintext, vector<u8>& key, unsigned r = 20)
    {
        vector<T> S(2 * r + 4);
        key_schedule(key, S, r);
        unsigned w = numeric_limits<T>::digits;

        for (auto block = plaintext.begin(); block != plaintext.end(); block += 4) {
            block[B] += S[0];
            block[D] += S[1];

            for (unsigned i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
                T t = rol(block[B] * (2 * block[B] + 1), log2(w));
                T u = rol(block[D] * (2 * block[D] + 1), log2(w));
                block[A] = rol((block[A] ^ t), u) + S[2 * i];
                block[C] = rol((block[C] ^ u), t) + S[2 * i + 1];
                T a = block[A];
                block[A] = block[B];
                block[B] = block[C];
                block[C] = block[D];
                block[D] = a;
            }
            block[A] += S[2 * r + 2];
            block[C] += S[2 * r + 3];
        }
    }

    /**
    * Decrypt @ciphertext using @key for @r rounds
    * @param plaintext: plain text to encrypt
    * @param key: key bytes
    * @param r: number of rounds
    */
    template<class T> static void decrypt(vector<T>& ciphertext, vector<u8>& key, unsigned r = 20)
    {
        vector<T> S(2 * r + 4);
        key_schedule(key, S, r);
        unsigned w = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;
        
        for (auto block = ciphertext.begin(); block != ciphertext.end(); block += 4) {
            for (unsigned i = r; i > 0; i--) {
                T d = block[D];
                block[D] = block[C];
                block[C] = block[B];
                block[B] = block[A];
                block[A] = d;
                T u = rol(block[D] * (2 * block[D] + 1), log2(w));
                T t = rol(block[B] * (2 * block[B] + 1), log2(w));
                block[C] = ror(block[C] - S[2 * i + 1], t) ^ u;
                block[A] = ror(block[A] - S[2 * i], u) ^ t;
            }
            
            block[D] -= S[1];
            block[B] -= S[0];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Asking for algorithmic spot checking, not debugging help.

Comment: Have you *tried* to use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see when and where it goes wrong?

Comment: Also please try to avoid one-character names, it makes the code very hard to understand. Please try to come up with semantically valuable names, that in short form describes the purpose of the variables. If you need to match the variables against some paper, use comments. And comments in general describing the algorithms (especially any possible deviations from the algorithm), what you do, and *why* you do it this specific way are also helpful. This helps for people reading the code without access to any papers.

Comment: Thanks for the definition of debugging, must be new to me. *Yes*.

Comment: Again, asking for algorithmic spot checking - the variable names are directly from the paper to help those looking at the algorithm.

Comment: @1fTBmq6q4DEaN2pnY -- Programs must be debugged -- algorithms need no debugging.  That's the difference.  How do we know there isn't just a bug in your program that has absolutely nothing to do with the algorithm?

Comment: @1fTBmq6q4DEaN2pnY Unfortunately the chances of somebody spotting the issue by just reading through the code is slim. What I've always done is to get a known good example and print out the intermediate values in hexadecimals (e.g. the values created by the key schedule) so that I can compare. heck, maybe those intermediate values can be found somewhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have a very robust Google test suite and removed all of my debugging pre-processor directives for clarity of the question. Fixed myself, it was an algorithmic problem as stated. Marking solved and going to cryptography.stackexchange next time...

Comment: It's https://crypto.stackexchange.com so not cryptography in full. Although you can request test vectors there, asking for debugging help is off topic.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes... Again, if anyone bothered to open the paper and spot check algorithm to code they would have seen where I fudged up. Not expecting people to be able to look at cryptography code and debug by staring. It is a 1:1 with the algorithm in the paper using C++ templates for different word sizes.